# Encrypt in SQLServer 2005, decrypt in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, security, encryption

I'm trying to find a way to encrypt a column in SQLServer 2005, with an algorithm easily decryptable from Java.

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) I see encryption by passphrase uses 3DES, but there's no other specification.

If usable, I'd encrypt with

```
EncryptByPassPhrase('Testpassphrase', 'plaintext')
```

convert to Hex and read it from a Java application. Is it possible or are there other convenient methods to achieve my goal?

In addition, a DBA shouldn't be able to decrypt the data without knowing the password.

Comment: Can you not use [`DecryptByPassphrase`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to reverse the operation, rather than seeking a solution in Java?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise. Problem is, a customer asked not to export plain data from the DB, and do the decryption at the Java-application level.